# Execution of KornShell (ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Any one has the idea of the below line:

```
path to file/filename.ksh help trunk help
```

Can any one explain the meaning of this and what it will do? I want to know why the last three words are used in the script? What will it do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a description of how to `execute` a `script` with three parameters:

1. `help` is argument 1
2. `trunk` is argument 2
3. `help` is argument 3

All of these arguments will be "sent" to the script called `filename.ksh`. However what the script does or if it even exists is impossible to say without actually seeing the script. To me this just looks like an example of how you **could** execute *a* script.

Answer (score 0):

indeed, and were i posting the example, i'd have given it to you as if it were a real command, as this is:

```
 $ /path/to/file/filename.ksh  help trunk help
```

assuming you recognize the '$' as the shell prompt, then you simply copy the remainder of the line and paste into your terminal window.  In this case, if the */path/to/file/filename.ksh*
is italic (I'm still learning **Markdown**),   then you understand it is an example, and you may be expected to supply your own directory path to an actual file, possibly one you have been instructed to write yourself.